# How to get the value of a sibling td textbox value?

Tags: jquery

I need the value of first td input type place holder value on last td button click, how can i get it. I am doing it following way.

```
 $(".prodcs").click(function () {
        var qty =$(this).prevAll(':eq(2)').find('#qty').attr('placeholder').val();
        //$(this).closest('td').find('#qty').val();
        alert(qty);
    });
```

But its not working.

```
 <tr>
                            <td width="170">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1" id="qty">
                            </td>
                            <td width="560">
    <select name="DDL" id="DDL" class="form-control"><option value="1">7''  - £10.00</option>
    <option value="2">14'' - £15.00</option>
    <option value="6">5''  - £5.00</option>
    <option value="7">500 M- £15.00</option>
    </select>                        </td>
                            <td width="102" align="right">
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-productid="3" id="product_3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg popup prodcs">Customisation</a>
                            </td>

                            <td width="101" align="right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 20px; color: #666"></i>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: what Tushar said-- you have `.attr('placeholder').val();`, drop the `.val()` if you want the placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `placeholder` attribute value using `.attr('placeholder');`

<strike>`var qty = $('#qty').attr('placeholder')`</strike>

---

**Update**

**id** must be **unique** use **class** instead.

[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
var qty =  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0) input").attr('placeholder');
```

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: Hah, I didn't even see the ID :( +1

Comment: but there are n number of input type with same id.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet -- You **cant** have ID's of the same value

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet Read [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: I want value kept in the place holder, i am not getting that value.

Comment: Attaching val function in the end says it is not a function. this is the error i am getting.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet if you want input's value Try `var qty =  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0) input").val()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var input = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first input");
```

Comment: I want value but it returns me the object too.

Comment: Yes, you have to call a function on it... try `.attr("placeholder")`

Comment: there is a problem it comes up with the default value of placeholder but when i manually change a value to other it doesn't come up with changed value still it comes up with default value of place holder.

Comment: Yes because that placeholder is constant...if you want the typed value just do `.val()`

Comment: TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find(...).attr(...).val is not a function

Comment: When i am attaching val in the end it says it is not a function.

Comment: You're missing the `()` at the end of `val`